# jQuery get sibling or closest element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, siblings, closest

I just can't get this tiny piece of code to work. I'm basically trying to get the sibling of the clicked ahref, but It just returns the clicked element itself (used `console.log()` to test this).

```
$('.script-vote').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this);

    href.siblings('.script-vote') //This doesn't work
        .removeClass('active');

    href.closest('.script-vote') //This doesn't work
        .removeClass('active');
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="one-half t-center">
    <a href="..." class="script-vote up" title="Upvoten">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
        <span class="score"><?=$post->getUpVotes()?></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="one-half t-center">
    <a href="..." class="script-vote down" title="Downvoten">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>
        <span class="score"><?=$post->getUpVotes()?></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

So when I click click the `.script-vote.up` element, I want to remove the `active` class of `.script-vote.down`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those aren't siblings, they have different parents

Comment: The `a` tags do not have any siblings, and closest only checks the parent chain, try `href.parent().next().find('.script-vote')`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reactions, I get it now. I used `href.parent().siblings().find('.script-vote').removeClass('active')` to fix my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <a> elements in your HTML do not have any siblings. But their parents do. Make sure that they are enclosed in a grand-parent div:

```
<div class="voting-container">
<div class="one-half t-center">
    <a href="..." class="script-vote up" title="Upvoten">
       <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
        <span class="score"><?=$post->getUpVotes()?></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="one-half t-center">
    <a href="..." class="script-vote down" title="Downvoten">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>
        <span class="score"><?=$post->getUpVotes()?></span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

You can refer to the following JavaScript with jQuery as an example:

```
$(".script-vote").click(function(){

    var otherVotingButton = $(this).parent().siblings(".one-half").first().find(".script-vote");

    otherVotingButton.css("background-color","red");     

    otherVotingButton.href="#";
    otherVotingButton
        .off() //remove original event handler
        .click(function() { alert("you already voted!");});
});
```

Get the sibling of the parent, then get the script-vote <a> element inside it.

Comment: My problem is solved, but for the effort and some extra info I will accept this answer :-).